# Trouble transferring schematic (working) to actual circuit (not working)

Tags: operational-amplifier

EDIT: At this point I'm just going to implement it in software. I give up. :< Thanks though!

So I keep screwing up this circuit, and the simulation works just fine.

The simulated circuit: <s>http://pastebin.com/fuWYgYjC</s>

[image: Schematic]

In the [rest of the album](https://imgur.com/a/mqTMC) now.

A sketch of how I put it onto the breadboard,

[image: Sketch]

and pictures thereof (are in the album linked above)

It's color-coded, so I can find mistakes more easily (didn't seem to help though). Red = V+, Black = V-, Green = GND, Yellow = Mic Input, Orange = LED Output. The op-amp I'm using is an LM741.

It's supposed to change the peak brightness of the LED depending on the ambient sound level. The frustrating thing is that the simulator is happy with it, but on the board, the op-amp can't even keep its inputs at the same voltage (4.4 V difference). The voltage drop on the resistors is wrong too, and I think that's caused by the former.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: do you have the schematic of the Falstad cct.?  Asking people to look over odd nodal netlists is akin to asking them to eat glass for you ...  ;)

Comment: Alright, I can embed it, I think?

Comment: Huh, CircuitLab isn't loading. This may take a while.

Comment: What kind of mic are you using?

Comment: It's some kind of condenser microphone, but I don't know more than that.

Comment: @HenrySwanson It's probably an electret microphone then.  These mics need to be capacitvely coupled and biased with a resistor, usually a couple of kiloohms.  Unfortunately, your circuit can't work as designed.  Try doing a search for "electret mic input stage" for some ideas.

Comment: R1-3 look way too small - any signal coming from the microphone will be swamped. In the simulation what did you set its amplitude to? What part number is it?

Comment: I tested it with an oscilloscope, and it is at max 80mV, s I set it to that. There don't seem to be any external markings on it. It's not one of the small cylindrical mics that are usually in electronics projects, it's boxy and square, so I think it was harvested from a commercial product of some sort.

Comment: See addition to my answer

Answer (score 3):

The circuit has too many "issues" to be quickly corrected, alas.
It bends the brain somewhat to understand what is intended.

Serious questions:
Where did you get the circuit?
Why do you think it may do what you want?

Resistor values are FAR too small.
eg at full swing I = 9V/50R = 180 mA.
Which the 741 will not do.

Depending on the simulator, simulator OPAMPS can have big muscly arms, lift 100 ton weights, swing rail to rail and accept input rail to rail, and more.
 Real world ones wont.

The LED is being voltage driven with no concern for what it thinks of this.
It will die in sorrow.

The circuit critically depends on the mic resistance.
Mic type affects what happens.
 Add a say 1 uF to 100 uF capacitor in series with the MIC.

BUT the circuit is still "just wrong".

Best to start again.
Explain what you want to do.
If you have a circuit that somebody else provided please  supply a link.

---

Added:

Had another quick glance.
A fatally fatally fatal problem is that IF the microphone is high impedance then the opamp is trying to place 1.7V across the LED. What this does depends on the LED type.
A white or blue one will do nowt.
 A red one may do summat. Or not.

...digs .. [LED is red 2V nominal](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTL-307EE.pdf)

If the microphone has a DC resistance of close to zero (moving coil) then Vout will be close to zero. Above that the mic DC resistance will affect the DCout setpoint.

Place a cap in series with microphone. If it is an electret type it will stop working. We'll deal with that next.

Increase all resistor values by ABOUT 100 times in value (or more.)

After scaling by 100x make R4 R5 bigger (just remove one) or the other 3 smaller so Vout DC is about 4V.

Add a 100 Ohm to 470 Ohm resistor in series with the LED.
eg if Vout is 4VDC and VLED is 2V and RLED series is 100 Ohm then ILED = (4-2)/100 = 20 mA.
Play

If no mic output place a 100k from MIC+ to V+ 9V (electret drive). (On mic side of the cap you added.)

It works.
(LED may be dead by now)

Report.